# How to force lowercase url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, webserver, cloudflare

How to force request lowercase in the URL in Cloudflare?

for example, if Cloudflare get requests for `https://example.com/signup/Test-Page-BLOG/` then it should be redirected to `https://example.com/signup/test-page-blog/`

Is that possible to use the Cloudflare page rule or any other method within Cloudflare?

Please advice.

Always thankful for this community.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloudflare workers for that. You can go to the workers section and paste this script:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

/**
 * Fetch and log a request
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
  let url = request.url
  // console.log('New url: ', url.toLowerCase())
  console.log('Got request', request.url)
  
  if (url.toLowerCase() !== request.url) {
    return new Response('', { status: 301, headers: { 'Location': url.toLowerCase() } });
  } else {
    let response = await fetch(request)
    console.log('Got response', response.url)
    return response
  }
}
```

Now on the right side, you will see a window where you can create a `GET` request and see the results.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It worked but all incoming requests are going through this code which isn't suitable for me in this situation. Please suggest if you have any alteranative.

Comment: Bro, there is a scenario here. When a URL matching a Workers script, it passes the request into the Workers runtime. Hence the request who needs to turn into a lowercase URL will be accounted by workers.

Comment: But in Cloudflare, only workers can help you to achieve these sorts of results.